# How to use Application and Plug.Router to listen on port with Elixir

Tags: elixir, elixir-mix, plug

I have this Application file:

```
defmodule MyApi do
  use Application

  def start(_type, _args) do
    children = [
      MyApi.Router
    ]

    opts = [strategy: :one_for_one, name: MyApi.Supervisor]
    Supervisor.start_link(children, opts)
  end
end
```

and then a router file like so:

```
defmodule MyApi.Router do
  use Plug.Router

  plug :match
  plug :dispatch

  # Dummy data to store items in memory
  @items [
    %MyApi.Item{id: 1, name: "Item 1", description: "Description for Item 1"},
    %MyApi.Item{id: 2, name: "Item 2", description: "Description for Item 2"}
  ]

  # Route to get all items
  get "/api/items" do
    send_resp(conn, 200, Jason.encode!(@items))
  end

  # Handle requests to unknown routes
  match _ do
    send_resp(conn, 404, "Not found")
  end
end
```

but when I run `ies -S mix` then project is not listening on a port.
I want to curl and hit this route:

```
bash-3.2$ curl http://localhost:4000/api/items
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 4000 after 9 ms: Connection refused
```

anyone know how to listen on a port and engage the router?

Comment: You need to install a plug adapter (like `plug_cowboy`) and pass that to `children`. See the example here: https://hexdocs.pm/plug/readme.html#supervised-handlers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the [Bandit docs](https://hexdocs.pm/bandit/Bandit.html#module-using-bandit-with-plug-applications):

1. Add `:bandit` to your list of deps in `mix.exs`
2. In `MyApi`, change `MyApi.Router` to `{Bandit, plug: MyApi.Router}`

Bandit is the newer pure Elixir web server, Cowboy is the older Erlang one. Both are mentioned in the [Plug installation docs](https://hexdocs.pm/plug/readme.html#installation).

Comment: damnit chapgpt didn't tell me about Bandit :)

Comment: Haha a win for Stack Overflow (which will feed the next LLM iteration... ).

Comment: it's always gonna be a month behind the times, however maybe you could push to GhatGPT instead of waiting for it to pull from you. Business opportunity? :) Pay to push to it maybe